# IDBDatabase.transaction is always null

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have been following the page [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).

When the page is loaded, I create/load the database.

```
window.App = window.App || {};
App.db = window.indexedDB.open("myapp", 1);
```

Following these, I define `onerror`, `onupgradeneeded` and `onsuccess` for `App.db` object.

In `onupgradeneeded`, I create a new object store.

Finally, the `onsuccess` method is called automatically by Javascript because the database is created/loaded. In this method, I list the details of `App.db`.

```
App.db.onsuccess = function(ev){
    console.dir( App.db );
};
```

Console shows that,

`readyState = "done"` `result = IDBDatabase` `transaction = null`

I called the page with file:///, http://localhost, http://myownserver.that.is.forwarded.to.127.0.0.1.from.domain.provider separately.

but the problem persists. The `transaction` method is null, and I can't do anything, start any transaction. What is the problem, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexedDB.open` returns a request object (`IDBRequest`). So your `App.db` will hold the request.

It sounds like you have a handle on the upgrade process.

Once that's complete, the connection object (an `IDBDatabase` instance) is returned via the `result` property of the request, and you use the `transaction()` method on the connection object to start transactions. So you'd want to write your `"success"` handler more like:

```
App.db.onsuccess = function(ev){
    var connection = App.db.result;
    var tx = connection.transaction(stores, mode);
    ...
};
```

But it's more common to call the connection object something like `db` and you don't need to hold on to the request once the connection is opened, so what you probably meant to do is something more like this:

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("myapp", 1);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  var db = openRequest.result;
  db.createObjectStore(...);
  ...
};
openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
  App.db = openRequest.result;
  var tx = App.db.transaction(...);
};
```